# CakePHP route where ID is at the end of slug

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want a route that will match any URL that has a particular regex at the end of it. I would have thought this would work:

`Router::connect("/*/:id",array('controller'=>'GeneralPages','action'=>'urlrewrite'),array('id'=>'[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}[=]'));`

which would match site.com/pages/page/sidoeido212=

But it doesn't go through to this route? Is there an issue using the wildcard at the begining or something?

Comment: Your RegEx... is that requiring exactly 11 alphanumeric characters, followed by an equals sign?

Comment: Yeah that's what it's after.

Comment: Is there another route that matches first?

Comment: even made this the ONLY route in there and it still doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
Router::connect("/*/:id", 
array('controller'=> 'GeneralPages','action' => 'urlrewrite'),
array('pass'=> array('id'), 'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}[=]'));
```

Comment: Tried that earlier, however it didn't work. The route doesn't match the URL. This is what's confusing me, that route SHOULD match - however I've never seen the wildcard used as anything but a catch all at the end of the url.